# Read how many cells have a certain color in Excel for Mac

Tags: macos, excel

I am using Office 2011 for Mac, in the Excel application, is it possible somehow to read how many cells in a row are red colored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an AppleScript that returns the column & row numbers of cells that have a red fill. Or are you looking for a language other than AppleScript?

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet
        set lastColumn to used range's last column's first column index
        set lastRow to used range's last row's first row index

        set redCells to {}
        repeat with columnCounter from 1 to lastColumn
            repeat with rowCounter from 1 to lastRow
                if column columnCounter's row rowCounter's interior object's color is {255, 0, 0} then
                    copy {columnCounter, rowCounter} to end of redCells
                end if
            end repeat
        end repeat

        return redCells
    end tell
end tell
```

I bet that a single-line script like `tell application "Microsoft Excel" to tell active sheet to return every cell of used range whose interior object's color is {255, 0, 0}` would run faster, but I can't figure out the exact wording.

Comment: I am looking for anything that works on mac os x; I do not care about the language, unless it works or I need to install any extra language/things,

Comment: Since you're using a Mac, there's nothing extra to install. Just paste the code into AppleScript Editor.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using VBA with the following code.  Put it in a module and run it from the sheet you want to check.

```
Sub GetRedCells()
    Dim rCell As Range, rRowRange As Range, iRow As Integer, iInteriorColour As Integer, iFontColour As Integer

    iRow = Application.InputBox("Enter Row Number")

    If iRow > 0 Then
        Set rRowRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, "A"), ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))

        For Each rCell In rRowRange
            If rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then iInteriorColour = iInteriorColour + 1
            If rCell.Font.Color = vbRed Then iFontColour = iFontColour + 1
        Next rCell

        MsgBox "You have " & iInteriorColour & " cell(s) that have a red interior " & vbCr & "and " & iFontColour & " cell(s) with a red font."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, Office 2011 for Mac has VBA, just go to Tools -> Macro -> Visual Basic Editor.  Then in the Project window on the left of the VBE right click anywhere in your project's tree and Insert -> Module. Paste the code and you can run it from the Tools -> Macro -> Macros menu or assign a shortcut key